# Dismiss or remove System Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-view, navigationbar

I want to dismiss bottom Navigation bar for one particular screen. 
I tried using

```
setSystemUiVisibility(HorizontalScrollView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

I have put this in Onscroll of my scrollView, ontouch of my views. 
but the issue is its comes back and the screen gets resize.

Any suggestions by which I can completely remove the NAVIGATION BAR. [image: I have marked the navigation bar which I want to remove completely for one screen.]

Answer (score 0):

Check out `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, this flag hides the navigation bar until the user interacts with the device. It's new in Android 4.0. You can enable this flag for example like this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView()
           .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Note that the navigation won't disappear again automatically, you have to set it every time after the user interacted with the device.

Alternatively you can make the navigation less obtrusive by using **SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE**, this changes the buttons into small dots (e.g. like the camera app).